# Getting Jordan basis and Jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried solving this matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}2&3&4\\-2&-2&-2\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ I came up with the eigenvalues as: $\lambda^2(\lambda-1)$. Which gives eigenvalues: $\lambda = 0$ (twice) and $\lambda = 1$.

But I have difficulties finding for the Jordan Basis for $A$? For finding $b_1$,$b_2$ and $b_3$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$??

Comment: What do you mean by "solving this matrix"?

Comment: It seems that $b_1, b_2, b_3$ are basis vectors that transfom $A$ into Jordan form, and "solving this matrix" means finding Jordan form.

Comment: Yes b1,b2,b3 are the basis vectors. But thats after plugging in lamda = 0 and lamda = 1 in A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda=0$, row-reduce
$$A-0I=\pmatrix{2&3&4\\-2&-2&-2\\1&1&1\\}
  \sim\pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&0\\}$$
to see that there is only one independent eigenvector.  So we need to consider the generalised eigenspace
$$\ker(A-0I)^2=\ker\pmatrix{2&4&6\cr-2&-4&-6\cr1&2&3\cr}
  =\ker\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr0&0&0\cr0&0&0\cr}\ .$$
You can completely solve this, but work can be saved by concentrating on what we need: we want a generalised eigenvector which is not an eigenvector.  That is, a vector which is a solution of this system but not of the previous one.  By trial and error
$$\pmatrix{1\cr1\cr-1\cr}$$
works.  Then you need $A-\lambda I$ times this:
$$(A-0I)\pmatrix{1\cr1\cr-1\cr}=\pmatrix{1\cr-2\cr1\cr}\ .$$
So your first two vectors in the Jordan basis could be
$$\pmatrix{1\cr-2\cr1\cr}\ ,\quad \pmatrix{1\cr1\cr-1\cr}$$
- make sure you put them in this order.  The third vector will be an eigenvector for $\lambda=1$.  I'll leave the rest up to you.

Comment: Thanks! How did you know that [1,1,-1] would work, what kind of trial error was used? I thought that we would have to pick a basis where it should be in ker(A−0I)2 and not in A−0I?

Comment: I just looked at it.  I'm sure you will be able to do this if you practise.  Until then, just solve to find a basis for $\ker(A-0I)^2$ and then start by picking one of your basis vectors which is not in $\ker(A-0I)$.